# Does R travis work on large data packages?

Tags: r, travis-ci

I seem to be running into a memory allocation issue when using R `travis-ci` on an R package that depends on a 90 Mb data package (i.e., that's where it gets its data from):

```
* installing *source* package ‘my_package’ ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in system2(file.path(R.home("bin"), "R"), c(if (nzchar(arch)) paste0("--arch=",  : 
  cannot popen ' '/home/travis/R-bin/lib/R/bin/R' --no-save --slave 2>&1 < '/tmp/RtmpGLG3uQ/file2f65432e469d'', probable reason 'Cannot allocate memory'
* removing ‘/home/travis/R/Library/my_package’
Warning in q("no", status = 1, runLast = FALSE) :
  system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
Error: Command failed (1)
Execution halted
The command "./travis-tool.sh github_package my_github_handle/my_package" failed and exited with 1 during .

Your build has been stopped.
```

Is it because `travis-ci` doesn't work with large data packages like this, or is it some other issue?

Related posts: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5713, https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3656

Here is my `travis.yml` file

```
language: r
cache: packages
warnings_are_errors: true
sudo: required
before_install:
 - curl -OL http://raw.github.com/craigcitro/r-travis/master/scripts/travis-tool.sh
 - chmod 755 ./travis-tool.sh
install:
 - ./travis-tool.sh aptget_install r-cran-xml
 - ./travis-tool.sh install_github hadley/devtools
 - ./travis-tool.sh install_deps
 - ./travis-tool.sh github_package my_github_handle/my_package
r_github_packages:
 - my_github_handle/my_package
```

Note that both of my R packages (both the main R package and the data package it requires) are both on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The later half of the `travis.yml` is not needed. Use:

```
language: r
cache: packages
warnings_are_errors: true
sudo: false
```

For other package dependencies use `devtools`' [`Remote:` keyword in `DESCRIPTION`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html) to specify repositories or opt to [create your own repository](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r-data-packages-in-external-data-repositories-using-the-additional_repositories-field/) and use it (**Disclaimer: I wrote this article**).

Travis images under this setup are restricted to having 4 GB of RAM. For more information on VM builds information see:

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Virtualization-environments

This performs well with large data packages.

Comment: So you're saying that the main package doesn't need to have a specification that says `r_github_packages`?  I used that because the main package depends on another package (and both are in github)

Comment: In a nut shell, yes due to `devtools`' `Remote:` keyword. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html for using